# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Can't resolve this issue. Whenever I import Layout I get the error above.
When I import other components they work just fine. At first I thought the name Layout was reserved so I changed it but still got the same error.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Layout from "./components/Layout/Layout";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Layout />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Footer from '../Footer/Footer'
import Quotes from '../Quotes/Quotes'
import './Layout.css'

class Layout extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='bgImg'>
                <div className='centered text-center align-items-center justify-content-center'>
                    <Quotes />
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Layout
```

**[image: Error Message]**

Comment: can you please remove Quotes and Footer component form Layout and try?

Comment: ^ And whichever one causes the issue, check that it's being exported correctly

Comment: Hey Joseph coul you try what happen if you don't import Layout.css into Layout component?

Comment: @RenjithP.N. Removing Quotes and Footer worked. I just realised I had not written code for the Footer component that is why it was not working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you exactly what you should do.
First, make you sure export the components properly:

```js
/* relevant imports */

class Quotes extends Component {
  /* component code */
}

export default Quotes
```

Second make you use the proper import semantic in your `Layout` component:

```js
import Quotes from '/path/to/your/component';
```

instead of

```js
import {Quotes} from '/path/to/your/component';
```